Unable to run the Prefect server on machine's IP address when using NSSM
I have configured Prefect server on our Windows VM so that it runs on the machine's IP address. Here's how I did it.
env\Scripts\activate.bat 
(env) prefect config set PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST='SERVER-IP-ADDRESS'
(env) prefect server start

 ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ _____ 
| _ \ _ \ __| __| __/ __|_   _| 
|  _/   / _|| _|| _| (__  | |  
|_| |_|_\___|_| |___\___| |_|  

Configure Prefect to communicate with the server with:

    prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL=http://SERVER-IP-ADDRESS:4200/api

View the API reference documentation at http://SERVER-IP-ADDRESS:4200/docs

Check out the dashboard at http://SERVER-IP-ADDRESS:4200

I used NSSM to run the server as a service on Windows. I used a batch file for this. Here's how the batch file looks like.
cd C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\prefect-server\env\Scripts
call activate.bat
prefect.exe server start

I ran this batch file on Command Prompt just to test, and it gives the same output as above. It runs on the machine's IP address.
I created the service using nssm install with the batch file as parameter. When I run the service either using nssm start or from Windows Services, Prefect server runs on the default IP address 127.0.0.1:4200 instead.
What did I miss here?

I found the solution.
Before posting this question, I have a hunch that nssm runs Prefect with a different environment regardless if you set it up before installing the service. nssm has an option to set environment variables.

I had to re-install the service. On this tab, I added PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=SERVER-IP-ADDRESS. I ran the service, and Prefect now runs on the machine IP address.
